# CSS Twitter Bootstrap overrides JavaScript style because it executes after script. How to execute script last?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am doing an iframe post message to the parent page. The iframe's content sends a POST message with width and height and I grab those to change the element's style after I receive the message. However, whenever I do that, twitter bootstrap is changing the style of the element( I can only assume that it is a timing issue ).

I tried wrapping the functionality of the message listener but the code then never executes. here it is:

```
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            window.onload = function() {
                console.log("loaded");
                var array = event.data.split(" ");
                addStyle(document.getElementById("outer-frame-form"), 
                    ['height', 'width', 'position', 'overflow'], 
                    [array[0],array[1],'relative','hidden'], 
                    true);
            }
        });

        function addStyle(element, properties, values, important) {
            // this will be run when the whole pa
                var i;
                var cssString = "";
                for (var i=0; i<properties.length; i++)
                {
                    //remove previously defined property
                    if (element.style.setProperty)
                        element.style.setProperty(properties[i], '');
                    else
                        element.style.setAttribute(properties[i], '');

                    cssString += properties[i] + ':' + values[i] + ((important) ? ' !important' : '') + '; '
                    console.log(properties[i]);
                }

                //insert the new style with all the old rules
                element.setAttribute('style', element.style.cssText + " " + cssString);
        }
```

What other ways can I use to wait and execute the script after all css is loaded, so twitter bootstrap won't be able to override it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over complicating this. In the template somewhere you will have a heading tag - this is where the bootstrap is loaded. Put your [CSS meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) below this - its "Cascading Style Sheet" so what ever is last takes priority

Comment: It is, and the height and width still get overridden.